# Use of coalesce function in SQL Query

Tags: sql, split, coalesce

I have a specific requirement where i have two tables as mentioned below: `Material Details` and `Specification Details`. What i have to do is split the `Sp_Code` column value using "-"(hyphen). And then find the `Material_Value` of the `Sp_Code` in `Material_Details` table.

For example:

If I split "CHA-REZ" using "-" then I have two values, "CHA" and "REZ". Now I have to find the Material_Value for CHA in Material_Details table:

- If the value of CHA is not present in Material_Code column of material_Details table then I need to search for the value of REZ in Material_Code column of Material_Details table.
- If both are not found i need to display it as blank.

Please find the below table for reference. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    Material_Details                               Specification_Details    
Material_Code   Material_Value                      Sp_Code     Value
ABC              Ammeter                            CHA-REZ      1
TAB              Table                              PAP-CHA      2
CHA              Chair                              TAB-BBV      3
PAP              Paper                              CNN-ASD      4
```

Comment: so you've chosen tags of `SQL`, `split` and `coalesce` - you know what you need to do, are you looking for someone to write the SQL for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to derive the 'foreign keys', then `LEFT JOIN` the `Material_Detail` table on to the subquery twice and `COALESCE` the columns required from the `Material_Detail` tables

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(md1.Material_Value, md2.Material_Value, '') Material_Value
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        SUBSTRING(Sp_Code, 1, CHARINDEX('-', Sp_Code, 1)-1) FK1,
        SUBSTRING(Sp_Code, CHARINDEX('-', Sp_Code, 1)+1, LEN(Sp_Code)-1) FK2
    FROM Specification_Details
) spec
LEFT JOIN Material_Details md1 ON spec.FK1 = md1.Material_Code
LEFT JOIN Material_Details md2 ON spec.FK2 = md2.Material_Code
```